# How can I pass values into component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this component:

```
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() active:boolean;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.active);
    }
}
```

You will notice that I've declared an `Input` that I pass in like this:

```
<mycomponent
    [active]="1 == 1"></mycomponent>
```

When this loads, the log statement in the constructor logs `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

@Input property bindings are first only available after the ngOnInit,

So you should do :

```
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() active:boolean; 

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.active);
    }
}
```

Also FYI :

From the docs :

> `ngOnInit`
>   Initializes  the directive/component after **Angular first displays the data-bound properties** and sets the directive/component's input properties.
>   Called once, after the first ngOnChanges.

More on [Life Cycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: I see. how do i use `this.active` to set a class, via `ngClass` for example? if the property is always undefined i cannot use it...

Comment: @dopatraman, it's not always undefined , it's undefined in the constructor but it's available in ngOnInit .And I didn't get your next question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to use this.active in your HTML template:

```
 <div *ngIf='active'>
   <span   [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-play': active}">
 <div>
```